# Stuck with For loop using fgets for finding duplicate strings that are adjacent to each other

Tags: c, string, for-loop, fgets

I'm trying to create a program that reads a text file and that grabs the first line and second line with fgets() storing them into separate arrays for comparison with strcmp() and then running that in a loop to go to the 2nd and 3rd line store it in character array then compare and repeated this process with all the lines until the end of file. I need help in how to do it using a for loop. This is my a.txt file:

```
Hello?
Hello?
Hello?


No answer? Let's try again:
Hello?
Tik
Tok
Tok
tok
```

This is what I'm getting back when I compile:

```
 dup
 L1 Hello?
 L2 Hello?
dup
 L1 Hello?
 L2 Hello?
no dup
 L1 Hello?
 L2 
no dup
 L1 Hello?
 L2 
no dup
 L1 Hello?
 L2 No answer? Let's try again:
dup
 L1 Hello?
 L2 Hello?
no dup
 L1 Hello?
 L2 Tik
no dup
 L1 Hello?
 L2 Tok
no dup
 L1 Hello?
 L2 Tok
no dup
 L1 Hello?
 L2 tok-----
this is the file name:a.txt
```

Not sure why its repeating Hello's instead of going to the next line Do I have to clear the array somehow? Any help would be awesome, thanks!

--I only inserted relevant code to this post, this isn't all of the code just fyi

```
char * filename =  argv[argc-1];

FILE *f; 
f = fopen(filename, "r");
if(f == NULL) 
{
      fprintf(stderr, "unable to open file\n");
      return 1;
}

char  line1[MAX_CHAR_FOR_LINE_INPUT];
char  line2[MAX_CHAR_FOR_LINE_INPUT];
    


for (char * j = fgets(line1, MAX_CHAR_FOR_LINE_INPUT,f); j != NULL; j  = fgets(line1, MAX_CHAR_FOR_LINE_INPUT,f) ){
    for (char * n = fgets(line2, MAX_CHAR_FOR_LINE_INPUT,f); n != NULL; n = fgets(line2, MAX_CHAR_FOR_LINE_INPUT,f) ){
        int value = strcmp(line1,line2); 
        if ( value == 0 ){
            printf("dup\n");
        }  
        else{
            printf("no dup\n");
        }
        printf("%s",line1);
        printf("%s",line2);
    }
    printf("-----\n");
}
```

Comment: The nested loops mean the outer loop reads once and the inner loop reads the rest of the lines to the end of the file. `strcmp` returns 0 when strings match, not 1. `printf("The file %s has %d lines\n ", filename, linecount +1);` doesn't make sense since `linecount` is not defined anywhere. If you are reading from the file before the code shown be sure to either close and reopen it or seek back to the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

Try this as a replacement for the nested for loops you've shown:

```
char line1[ MAX_CHAR_FOR_LINE_INPUT ];
char line2[ MAX_CHAR_FOR_LINE_INPUT ];

fseek( f, 0, SEEK_SET ); // Be sure reading starts at start of file

for( ;; ) { // a "for ever" loop, to be exited somewhere in the code block
    if( fgets( line1, sizeof line1, f ) == NULL ) {
        printf( "At end of file\n" );
        break;
    }
    if( fgets( line2, sizeof line2, f ) == NULL ) {
        printf( "At end of file on unpaired line\n" );
        break;
    }

    if( strcmp( line1, line2 ) == 0 ) // return 0 means "the same"
        puts( "dupe" );
    else
        puts( "no dupe" );

    printf( "%s", line1 );
    printf( "%s", line2 );

    printf("-----\n");
}
```

It clearly, separately loads first one buffer, then the other, then compares those two (printing stuff), then starts all over again.

**EDIT:** Asked about the infinite `for()` loop above sparked a thought...

Here are two more alternatives for the "loop control":

```
while(  fgets( line1, sizeof line1, f ) != NULL ) { // got one??
    if( fgets( line2, sizeof line2, f ) == NULL ) { // try for another...
        printf( "At end of file on unpaired line\n" );
        break;
    }
    /* ... */
    printf("-----\n");
}

// Or...

while( fgets( line1, sizeof line1, f ) != NULL
    && fgets( line2, sizeof line2, f ) != NULL ) { // try for both

    /* ... */

    printf("-----\n");
}
```

**EDIT FINAL:**
The OP has clarified (in comments below) that the objective is to compare ***EACH*** line with ***ALL*** of its successors.

Since I know I will be paid for this... Here we go:

```
fseek( f, 0, SEEK_SET ); // Be sure reading starts at start of file

size_t offset = ftell( f );

for( ;; ) { // a "for ever" loop, to be exited somewhere in the code block
    fseek( f, offset, SEEK_SET ); // rewind
    if( fgets( line1, sizeof line1, f ) == NULL ) {
        printf( "At end of file\n" );
        break;
    }
    offset = ftell( f ); // remember this location for next round
    printf( "\n%s", line1 ); // one line in the kitty

    // now, read and compare all subsequent lines...
    while( fgets( line2, sizeof line2, f ) == NULL ) {
        char *eval = "no";
        if( strcmp( line1, line2 ) == 0 ) // return 0 means "the same"
            eval = "dupe >>";

        printf( "%-9s%s", eval, line2 );
    }
    printf("-----\n");
}
```

Comment: @JosueNunez I've added a comment. `for( ;; )` is one form of an 'infinite loop' that relies on code _inside_ the loop to terminate the loop. :-)

Comment: Okay I see, although what would be an alternate way of doing it more similar to the conventional for loop without using for(;;).

Comment: @JosueNunez `for( ; true; )`, `for( ; 1 == 1; )`, `while( 1 )`... `for()` and `while` (and `do/while`) are C's "loop" syntax. Different people use different conventions. My preferred is shown above...

Comment: the problem with the one you gave me after trying it was that the first array skips from line 1 to line 3 after, instead it should be assigned line 2 and compared against line 3 not automatically comparing lines 3 and 4 after.

Comment: @Fe203, thats why i tried putting it in a for loop to start off not a while loop because of the reason above^

Comment: @JosueNunez Please show me where your question says "I want to compare each line against ALL the lines that follow." The title of this question clearly states `duplicate strings that are **adjacent to each other**` ... "Anyway... look again.. (You have to be able to formulate *questions* if you want to be a programmer who can formulate **answers**.)